# Milky Oil in the radiator - Mazda 323

Tags: engine, oil, mazda, radiator

My vehicle has oil in the radiator and I have checked the head gasket matter fact I replaced it with a new one and there still is oil In the radiator 
may I ask what could be another reason for oil to be in the radiator?

Answer (score 2):

If milk-like oil ends up in the radiator despite replacing the head gasket, it is likely that the head itself has warped due to overheating, allowing oil to leak into the coolant channels.

While there is a remote possibility to salvage the cylinder head by having it skimmed by a professional machinist, in all probability it will need to be replaced.

Comment: On my 98 Dodge Dakota 3.9L, oil and coolant can mix if the head gasket, the intake manifold gasket, or the timing chain cover gasket go bad.  Do other engines, such as that in his Mazda 323, not have those other two weak points?  I realize every engine is different, but if he says he replaced the head gasket, couldn't it be that another gasket is blown?  I'm not criticizing, just asking because I don't know enough.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski : There could be other weak points for sure - a leaking oil cooler could also allow the two to mix. However, the milky appearance of the oil would suggest the engine has overheated, which more often than not results in a warped head. One way to confirm it would be to see a wide spread in the results of the compression test across cylinders.